# Why isn't my API data showing in a list view, when the GET request is successful?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I am working with flutter for the first time and having issues understanding why my data will not show. For context, the API returns a list of (physical) libraries and their current occupancy. I have correctly implemented an API get request, got the data outputted in the terminal (printed) and thus I know my API call is working. I also implemented the data received from the JSON as a list using my data model, and then I created a body with the library name and occupancy as a ListTile. Nothing is shown when compiled on the device screen, just a blank screen, no circular progress indicator either.

Here is my home page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/post.dart';
import '../services/remote_service.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // Declare a list of Libraries
  List<Libraries> _libraries = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call the getPosts function when the HomePage is initialized
    _getPosts();
  }

  // Function to make the GET request and store the response in a list of Libraries
  void _getPosts() async {
    var api = getDataAPI();
    var librariesJson = await api.getPosts();
    // Use the librariesFromJson function to convert the JSON string to a list of Libraries
    setState(() {
      _libraries = librariesFromJson(librariesJson!) as List<Libraries>;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Library Occupancy'),
      ),
      body: _libraries == null
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _libraries.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                // Display the library name and occupancy in a ListTile
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(_libraries[index].webster.occupancy),
                  subtitle:
                      Text(_libraries[index].webster.lastRecordTime.toString()),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my API request code (remote_service.dart):

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:xconcordia/models/post.dart';

class getDataAPI {
  Future<String?> getPosts() async {
    var credentials = '520:276377ba5206683e51d50fb86c378dc5';
// Encode the credentials in base64 format
    var base64Credentials = base64Encode(utf8.encode(credentials));

    var headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic $base64Credentials'};

    var request = http.Request('GET',
        Uri.parse('https://opendata.concordia.ca/API/v1/library/occupancy/'));
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String json = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      // ignore: await_only_futures
      Libraries library = await librariesFromJson(json);
      print("webster: " + library.webster.occupancy);
      return library.webster.occupancy;
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And finally, here is my JSON data model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Libraries librariesFromJson(String str) => Libraries.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String librariesToJson(Libraries data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Libraries {
  Libraries({
    required this.webster,
    required this.vanier,
    required this.greyNuns,
  });

  GreyNuns webster;
  GreyNuns vanier;
  GreyNuns greyNuns;

  factory Libraries.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Libraries(
        webster: GreyNuns.fromJson(json["Webster"]),
        vanier: GreyNuns.fromJson(json["Vanier"]),
        greyNuns: GreyNuns.fromJson(json["GreyNuns"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Webster": webster.toJson(),
        "Vanier": vanier.toJson(),
        "GreyNuns": greyNuns.toJson(),
      };
}

class GreyNuns {
  GreyNuns({
    required this.occupancy,
    required this.lastRecordTime,
  });

  String occupancy;
  DateTime lastRecordTime;

  factory GreyNuns.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GreyNuns(
        occupancy: json["Occupancy"],
        lastRecordTime: DateTime.parse(json["LastRecordTime"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Occupancy": occupancy,
        "LastRecordTime": lastRecordTime.toIso8601String(),
      };
}
```

Also, when I run this code, here is the terminal output:

```
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 302ms.
flutter: webster: .0000
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
.0000
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
#6      librariesFromJson (package:xconcordia/models/post.dart:3:68)
#7      _HomePageState._getPosts.<anonymous closure> (package:xconcordia/views/home_page.dart:28:20)
#8      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1114:30)
#9      _HomePageState._getPosts (package:xconcordia/views/home_page.dart:27:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: You have an error in output. Check data that you receive from API (in debugger, and `print` to logs).

Comment: @fartem Right, however, notice I print the data "webster: .0000" inside the API call and after its called. The data seems to be right, so i'm unsure. Can you expand on what you mean, if im misinterpreting what you said?

Comment: Why are you not using Provider or any other State Management library?

Comment: Also, Is this stream based API or normal GET API? Please confirm and revert. Incase, if it is stream based UI screen will render StreamBuilder()

Comment: @Prashant This is a normal GET API. I haven't looked into provider yet. I am learning the basics so I just wanted to create a simple app to show the get request data on the home screen for now, as a sort of sandbox app to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify Your Model Class

Convert the data to String in modal class:

```
  factory GreyNuns.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GreyNuns(
        occupancy: json["Occupancy"].toString(),
        lastRecordTime: DateTime.parse(json["LastRecordTime"].toString()),
      );
```

Comment: Naw, still didn't fix it. Any other ideas? I'm utterly lost. Thanks for the help for now.